# Python identify index on Dictionary with array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, indexing, key-value

I would like to get the index of the following key, value pair:

```
Key => [CorrectionHistory][Key] Value => 456

{'CorrectionHistory': [{'key': 123, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'}, {'CorrChngDesc': 'Commodity Line Changed'}]}, {'key': 456, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'AC Added/Modified'}, {'CorrChngDesc': 'CMDY Added/Modified'}]}, {'key': 789, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'AC Added/Modified'}]}}
```

Can someone please throw some light on this?

Comment: can you show us your desired output

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you have only the `CorrectionHistory` key as this is your example. In my example the function i wrote is very simple, just to prove is gets the job you mentioned done, but it can be easily generalized:

```
a = {
        'CorrectionHistory': [
            {'key': 123, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'}, {'CorrChngDesc': 'Commodity Line Changed'}]},
            {'key': 456, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'AC Added/Modified'}, {'CorrChngDesc': 'CMDY Added/Modified'}]},
            {'key': 789, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'AC Added/Modified'}]}
        ]
    }


def get_index_for_key(key):
    for index, item in enumerate(a['CorrectionHistory']):
        if item['key'] == key:
            return index
    return None


print(get_index_for_key(456))
```

Result: `1` the index you are looking for

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Also one liner:

```
data = {'CorrectionHistory': [{'key': 123, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'Discount Line Changed'}, {'CorrChngDesc': 'Commodity Line Changed'}]}, {'key': 456, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'AC Added/Modified'}, {'CorrChngDesc': 'CMDY Added/Modified'}]}, {'key': 789, 'CorrectionsAll': [{'CorrChngDesc': 'AC Added/Modified'}]}]}

index = [i for i, x in enumerate(data['CorrectionHistory']) if x['key'] == 456][0]
```

Output:

```
1
```